# How to setup Webhook to get notified whenever use has changed his password?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I have a app where users can signup/login with their FB account. How can I setup a webhook on my fb app that whenever the fb user changes his password then I get the callback?

Following thing is mentioned in the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/webhooks/

but there is no way to set that up on the app. Even the UI given looks old.

Let me know if anyone has any idea

Comment: What you are referring to, is specific to Workplace apps. Is your app one ...?

Comment: @CBroe yes workplace app